# Token fee in my contract error in pancakeswap

Tags: error, pancakeswap

I have created a logic in my contract by modifying the transfer function, so that it debits from the total amount arriving the taxes I need, then those taxes are sent to the same contract and continues with sending the remaining amount to the receiver indicated when Transfer was called. Then, before finishing the Transfer function I call another function in my contract that is in charge of exchanging the taxes (that are in my token) for WBNB or BNB and send them to another wallet. and finishes the Transfer function returning true.

My problem is that, when I have already created the LP in pancakeswap, and everything well configured, I send from my wallet an amount of token to another wallet and the tax debit, conversion and sending the tax and the remaining amount to the receiver is done correctly. But when I try to buy token in pancakeswap I get the error:

Execution reverted with reason: Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED.

I have already tried to see the documentation and not specific without giving support to the developers.  I thank in advance anyone who can help me.

Comment: Did you write the contract? If not, is there a hard coded address for a different implementation somewhere? In these cases, can start by checking the constants like v2 Router address, then at looking which addresses may need to be excluded from fees, like the pool. Else can simulate the transaction for more details on failure.